# Pass unknown class extending parent, then call functions of parent (Java)

Tags: java, function, parent, extends

I know that all classes passed to the function will be extending JComponent, but I don't know what the classes are themselves.

My code is specific, but what I am asking is more general.
In my code I am attempting to pass an unknown class that extends JComponent for the purpose of calling the JComponent method of setFont() on the class.

I have written this up as:

```
    public void setCustomFont(String ttfFile, Class<? extends JComponent> jc){
      try {
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(ttfFile)));
      } catch (IOException|FontFormatException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
      jc.super.setFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT);
    }
```

`jc.super.setFont(` gives the error: `jc cannot be resolved to a type`

while `((JComponent) jc).setFont(` gives the error: `Cannot cast from Class<capture#1-of ? extends JComponent to JComponent>`

and finally `jc.setFont(` gives the error: `the method setFont(int) is undefined for the type Class<capture#1-of ? extends JComponent>`

So, I honestly cannot figure out how to call functions of a parent through the child passed to a class.

Comment: This is just probably my ignorance, but shouldn't you be passing an instance of `JComponent` and not `Class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass the class to the function.

Just pass the object itself:

```
public void setCustomFont(String ttfFile, JComponent jc){
    ...
    jc.setFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT);
}
```

The `setFont` method is not a class method, it's an instance method, so you need an actual object that implements JComponent in order to call the method.

By defining the parameter as `JComponent jc`, the method will only accept objects that extend from JComponent, without knowing the specific class.

Comment: So, when calling the function `setCustomFont()` I would pass the class that extends `JComponent` to it, or the `JComponent` instance? So if `Blah` extends `JComponent`, i could say `setCustomFont("file.ttf",Blah);`? Or `setCustomFont("file.ttf",Blah.super)`?

Comment: No, not the class. The actual object that you want to set the font to. Like if you have 'JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Some text")', you need to pass 'label1' to the function.

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly. I guess I was thinking that if I called it a `JComponent` on the function side, it would lose it's child bits and only retain the `JComponent` portion of the object.

Answer (score 0):

The polymorphic behavior is applicable to the object hierarchy. What you are passing is the Class instance associated with the JComponent object which has no idea about the JComponent methods. And you cannot obviously cast the JComponent class to JComponent object.